# How can I upload images to google photos using playwright?

Tags: python, selenium, playwright

I am creating a python playwright bot for google photos, but I can't upload photos using playwright. For uploading the file I need to access the input element but it's only open when I click the upload > computer then the input shows up, but the problem is it's also opened the file choose window and I don't know how can I close that using playwright

I want to upload images to google photos using python playwright please help me.
In the image you will see that a window has popup to select file to upload but I don't want the window to pop up:

[image]

```
page.locator(selector='span[class="NlWrkb snByac"]').click()
sleep(3)
options = page.query_selector_all('div[class="jO7h3c"]')
options[2].click()
sleep(5)
page.locator('input[type="file"]').set_input_files('F:/python practice/googlephotosbot/big data.jpeg')
```

this code uploading the file but it can't close the window that is pop up in the picture please help me to solve the problem

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: yes i added code please help